# sIFR - Can't 'textalign' my tag - frustrated

Tags: sifr

Greetings!  Started experimenting with sIFR3 today and am in love!  So great!

For the life of me, however, I can't get what seems to be something so trivial to happen:  Center align my  tag:

[Example Page Here](http://pvpef.org/staging/index-1.shtml)

In my sifr-config.js, I have:

sIFR.replace(serif, {
  selector: 'h2', css: '.sIFR-root { textalign: center; }'
});

.. and yet no joy.

Any feedback and direction would most appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Ugh!  Thanks, Jason.  Yea, not enough coffee this morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That'd probably be because the valid CSS property name is `text-align`, not `textalign`.